# Read JSON Data from URL (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

Attempt 2 to get my question right (please bear with me - I'm new).

I am trying to read data from a URL

http://test.fhir.org/r3/Patient?family=smith&given=peggy&_format=json

and want to use Javascript to reformat it to the screen as table but

(1) I can't get it to read and

(2) I can't format it to a table as in json2table.com

Can anyone help?  Here is the code I am trying.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Playing with JSON</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

      <style type="text/css">
        .row{ margin-top: 20px}
      </style>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){

        console.log('loading event handlers');
        var $response = document.getElementById("response");
        var $getReposBtn = document.getElementById("get-repos");
        $getReposBtn.onclick = function(){
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.timeout = 2000;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e){
                console.log(this);
                if (xhr.readyState === 4){
                    if (xhr.status === 200){
                        // debugger;
                        // console.log(xhr.response);
                        $response.innerHTML = xhr.response;
                    } else {
                        console.error("XHR didn't work: ", xhr.status);
                    }
                }
            }
            xhr.ontimeout = function (){
                console.error("request timedout: ", xhr);
            }
            xhr.open("get", "http://test.fhir.org/r3/Patient?family=smith&given=peggy&_format=json", /*async*/ true);
            xhr.send();
        }
        });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">In Development</div>
        <div class="row">
            <button id="get-repos">JSON download trial!!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <pre id="response"></pre>
        </div>
    </div>

      <script>
        if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
          window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
            height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
            slug: "9f7sb409"
          }], "*")
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example you are assuming jQuery is present by having bootstrap.js loaded. This is not the case and you either need to load jQuery before bootstrap OR move your script to the bottom of the page (right before the body is closed) and remove this `$(window).load(function(){})`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Playing with JSON</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .row {
      margin-top: 20px
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">In Development</div>
    <div class="row">
      <button id="get-repos">JSON download trial!!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <pre id="response"></pre>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "9f7sb409"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    console.log('loading event handlers');
    var $response = document.getElementById("response");
    var $getReposBtn = document.getElementById("get-repos");
    $getReposBtn.onclick = function () {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.timeout = 2000;
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        console.log(this);
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.status === 200) {
            // debugger;
            // console.log(xhr.response);
            $response.innerHTML = xhr.response;
          } else {
            console.error("XHR didn't work: ", xhr.status);
          }
        }
      }
      xhr.ontimeout = function () {
        console.error("request timedout: ", xhr);
      }
      xhr.open("get", "http://test.fhir.org/r3/Patient?family=smith&given=peggy&_format=json", /*async*/ true);
      xhr.send();
    }

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you decide to use jQuery, your code can be simplified a lot:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Playing with JSON</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .row {
      margin-top: 20px
    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">In Development</div>
    <div class="row">
      <button id="get-repos">JSON download trial!!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <pre id="response"></pre>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "9f7sb409"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>

  <script>
    $(function () {
      console.log('loading event handlers');

      $("#get-repos").click(function onClick() {
        var url = "http://test.fhir.orgs/r3/Patient?family=smith&given=peggy&_format=json";

        $.getJSON(url, function onSuccess(response) {
          $("#response").text(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry it's still not working - I have used the second version - less is more right? - and I just can't seem to get it to run.

Comment: @RSimons Which browser are you using? How are you running this file? You need to test this on a local server (that is your web browser url must start with `http://...` not with `file:///...`). Are you getting any cross domain errors in the terminal?

Comment: Thanks Erick, yes I am running this on Chrome as a server and I can get a JSON output if I use the link - http://test.fhir.org/r3/Patient?family=smith&given=steven&_format=JSON 
I just can't get it back into the window on the page... very frustrating.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the terminal? DevTools are usually very good to debug this kind of errors. Use break points to test if your code is entering where it is supposed to or if something else is breaking.